# Navigation Bar Hidden Push View Height Difference

Tags: ios, xamarin, navigation, navigationbar, navigationcontroller

I have a root view controller that has navigation bar set hidden. When I push a new view on top, the view.height does not calculate the hidden nav bar space and is pushed to the top, with a bottom white space that is equal to that of navigation bar height. How do I fix it so that the height includes the white space as well? This is the snippet where I push the view:

```
    public void PushDetailView(NSIndexPath indexPath, ulong eventId)
    {
        BrowseDetailViewController detailViewController = new BrowseDetailViewController(indexPath, eventId);

        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(detailViewController, true);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you by any chance manually setting the height of the `view`?

Comment: i dont think so, i only have navigation set hidden in the first view. The problem is that if navigation bar is not hidden then the view displays properly, the second view's view height is equal to the height that is supposed to be displayed with a showing navigation bar.

Comment: How do you hide the navigation ? can you attach that code ?

Comment: That's weird. Hiding the navigation bar shouldn't affect the height of the second view. Maybe attach your code...?